# Fetch data from MSSQL through Python

Tags: python-2.7

Please can you help me to fetch data from MSSQL Server by help of python programming language. I need simple implementation like using select command to get all table data and use procedure to manipulate data. Also which module will be use for build communication between python and MSSQL.

Comment: Have you tried to use [pymssql](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/)?

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='SQL01', user='user', password='password', database='mydatabase')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(%d, %s)", \
    [ (1, 'John Doe'), (2, 'Jane Doe') ])
conn.commit()  # you must call commit() to persist your data if you don't set autocommit to True

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s', 'John Doe')
row = cur.fetchone()
while row:
    print "ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row[0], row[1])
    row = cur.fetchone()

# if you call execute() with one argument, you can use % sign as usual
# (it loses its special meaning).
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep LIKE 'J%'")

conn.close()
```

Comment: if it solved your query then upvote and accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

I used this code and it worked perfectly.

```
from os import getenv
import pymssql

server = getenv("PYMSSQL_TEST_SERVER")
user = getenv("PYMSSQL_TEST_USERNAME")
password = getenv("PYMSSQL_TEST_PASSWORD")

conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
IF OBJECT_ID('persons', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE persons
CREATE TABLE persons (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    salesrep VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
""")
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO persons VALUES (%d, %s, %s)",
    [(1, 'John Smith', 'John Doe'),
     (2, 'Jane Doe', 'Joe Dog'),
     (3, 'Mike T.', 'Sarah H.')])
# you must call commit() to persist your data if you don't set autocommit to True
conn.commit()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s', 'John Doe')
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print("ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row[0], row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()
```